# Не работает LDAP авторизация Gitlab

Tags: авторизация, gitlab, ldap

Дано: **Gitlab 12.5.5-ce.0.el7** (на 2х предыдущих версиях симптомы такие же), AD, конфигурация **gitlab.rb**:

```yaml
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-EOS
main:
 label: 'LDAP'
 host: '10.95.5.78'
 port: 389
 encryption: 'plain'
 uid: 'sAMAccountName'
 method: 'plain'
 bind_dn: 'gitlabat@msk.russb.org'
 password: 'password'
 timeout: 60
 active_directory: true
 allow_username_or_email_login: true
 block_auto_created_users: false
 base: 'CN=Users,DC=msk,DC=russb,DC=org'
EOS
```

После `reconfigure`, и запуска теста `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check[20]` получаю:

```bash
Checking LDAP ...

LDAP: ... Server: ldapmain
LDAP authentication... Success
LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 20 results)

Checking LDAP ... Finished
```

Т.е. список пуст, хотя авторизация пройдена

Далее была найдена  страница с дебагингом ([Документация gitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap.html#debug-ldap-user-filter-with-ldapsearch))

если выполнить

```bash
ldapsearch -h ldap://10.95.5.78 -p 389 -x -w "password" -D "gitlabat@msk.russb.org" -b "cn=Users,dc=msk,dc=russb,dc=org" "(sAMAccountName=*dmitriev*)" -v
```

То все успешно находится (отображаются данные пользователей)
Если убрать cn=Users - просто дольше выполняется, потому что поиск идет не только в cn Users. Пробовал подставлять вместо cn ou (конфиг гитлаба) - без изменений.

При всём при этом Gitlab залочил пользователя с доменной почтой (но сам пользователь не доменный, был заведен ранее в локальной базе GitLab)
разлок через `sudo gitlab-rails console production` пишет что всё ОК, но по факту пользователь остается залоченным.

P.S.

Сам я не силен в AD и LDAP. Не могу осилить настройку.

P.S.S.

Успешно настроена LDAP авторизация в Jenkins, но это конечно, не показатель.

Подозреваю что что-то не так с  CN/OU и прочими вводными, но я в них профан. Доменный админ примерно расписал как и что, но сказал что CN/OU Users Мне достаточно должно быть(как я понял, разные системы по разному так же понимают cn/ou).
Помогите, коллеги.

Answer (score 0):

Решилось всё банально просто - убрал из `base:` `CN=Users`
Плюс ко всему, в старых версиях Gitlab не требовалось прописывать принудительно `encryption: 'plain'` Т.е, по умолчанию TLS не применялся.
В моем случае я перебирал варианты CN/OU и прочие без этого параметра. И только под конец включил, но при этом оставил `base: CN=Users`.

итоговый рабочий вариант выглядит следующим образом:

```js
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-EOS
main:
 label: 'LDAP'
 host: '10.95.5.78'
 port: 389
 encryption: 'plain'
 uid: 'sAMAccountName'
 method: 'plain'
 bind_dn: 'gitlabat@msk.russb.org'
 password: 'password'
 timeout: 60
 active_directory: true
 allow_username_or_email_login: true
 block_auto_created_users: false
 base: 'DC=msk,DC=russb,DC=org'
EOS
```